# How to get value from Material UI textfield after pressing enter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I **cannot** get input value with this code. I tried with `onKeyUp, onKeyDown` and `onKeyPress` but these are not worked because not return the value. Normally get value with `onChange` property but it triggers every entered new character.

```
<TextField
  style={{ margin: 8 }}
  placeholder="Add a task"
  fullWidth
  margin="normal"
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      console.log("Enter key pressed");
      // write your functionality here
    }
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `e.target.value` you can get the input value. Add `e.preventDefault` to avoid an unexpected behavior:

```
  const onKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      console.log('Input value', e.target.value);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  <TextField
     ...
     onKeyPress={onKeyPress}/>
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xmh1e)

Comment: after putting *onKeyPress={onKeyPress}* property it doesn't trigger exactly. Because it is not a property of material UI textfield API. https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api I tried with this answer but it doesn't work when getting value.

Comment: @SupunSandaruwan Did you check the working example? according to the component implementation it receive other props, and onKeyPress is a synthetic event, see https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js take a look at how ...others are attached to TextFieldRoot

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation and answer. I got new thing.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, most of the time if you wish to have this behavior, you are most likely creating a form. So wrap the `TextField` in a `form` and implement the `onSubmit` event.

Answer (score 0):

This is also working code for this.

```
<TextField
                style={{ margin: 8 }}
                placeholder="Add a task"
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"

                inputProps={{
                  onKeyPress: (event) => {
                    if (event.key === "Enter") {
                      // write your functionality here
                      event.preventDefault();
                    }
                  },
                }}

              />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add an onChange handler. Then your Enter can be used however you want, e.g., to submit the value. Something like this:

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>()

    const handleChangeText = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setValue(event.target.value);
    };


return (
        <TextField
          style={{ margin: 8 }}
          placeholder="Add a task"
          fullWidth
          margin="normal"

          inputProps={{
            onKeyPress: (event) => {
              if (event.key === "Enter") {
                // write your functionality here
                event.preventDefault();
              }
            },
          }}

          onChange={handleChangeText}
        />
)
```

Comment: onChange is triggering when everytime that i entering character. I want trigger function only after pressing enter button.